# Deleting Arrays With Pointers--Multidimensional and Multipointer---in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, delete-operator

So I know multiple dimensions/arrays can get confusing, but how do I delete these types of arrays properly? I know the syntax, but adding multiple dimensions/pointers gets tricky. Here's some snippet code:

```
  //FIRST PROBLEM
  //function to add an item to a pointer array
  //due to problems in adding something directly, I created a temp
  //temp is not necessary if there's a way without it
  int y = 6;
  int x = 5;
  int *myList = new int[x];
  void List::add(int newInt)
  {
      void List::add(int newInt){
      int *temp = new int[x+1];
      temp = myList;
      temp[x+1] = newInt;
      delete [] myList;
      int *myList = temp;
  }

 //SECOND PROBLEM----tricky multidimensional
 // not getting any errors, but not sure if done properly
 int x;
 int y;
 int** myMatrix;
 cout << "How many rows?" << endl;
 cin >> x;
 myMatrix = new int*[x];
 cout << "How many columns?" << endl;
 cin >> y;
 for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
     myMatrix[i] = new int[y];
 for(int i=0; i<10; ++i){
     for(int j=0; j<10; ++j){
         myMatrix[i][j] = rand();
     }  
     for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; ++i)
     {
         for(int j = 0 ; j < col ; ++j){
           //  delete[] myMatrix[i][j]; (tried this method, did not work)
         }
         delete[] myMatrix[i];
     }
     delete[] myMatrix;
  //looked around for examples, but were all different enough to not help
  //
```

Comment: _"but how do I delete these types of arrays properly?"_ In the reverse order as they were allocated.

Comment: Your code looks right. You don't need that innermost loop.

Comment: The line temp[y+1] = newInt; is giving me an error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: @JCoder That's another question. Doesn't has something to do with your title, or questions made up. `y + 1` is clearly out of bounds with the allocation, since `7` is biigger than `5`.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ, Updated, there's still the same error

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I think the question has been resolved. The problem was I tried temp = myList;. I forgot that just because I made  int *temp = new int[x+1]; that temp's length was still x and not x+1. This is something I hope a language in the future that goes back to using pointers will fix (C++ is a tricky language, I think even C++ experts in the language would agree, when compared to other languages). In a future, more Java-like language, I would like to treat pointers and what they point to like objects that inherit each other's qualities. // some relevant C++ notes

Comment: @JCoder You don't use pointers in c++ as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> //  delete[] myMatrix[i][j]; (tried this method, did not work)
> ```

The code you have here

```
myMatrix[i][j] = rand();
```

doesn't allocate any new heap memory for `myMatrix[i][j]` (which is of a non pointer type, but a simple `int` BTW), but just assigns the result of `rand()` as a value there.

Thus it's not necessary/wrong, you ever call `delete` for it.

---

You only call `delete`/`delete[]` as counterparts of `new`/`new[]` in the reverse order as they were allocated.

Further, to get redeemed from struggling with memory management, I'd seriously recommend using a c++ standard container like `std::vector<std::vector<int>> myMatrix;` instead of managing raw pointers.

Comment: right, thanks, that makes sense, because it's not a pointer. But **matrix is a double pointer and matrix is a pointer array, so I still have to delete those...

Comment: @JCoder _"so I still have to delete those"_ Well, as mentioned: _Do that in reversed order_. Though, consider last part of my answer, mentioning `std::vector<std::vector<int>> myMatrix;`.